# Creating a fixed vhd with empty data

Tags: azure, vhd

Is it possible to create a vhd of **2 GB** ,
 which contains 1 GB of data and remaining 1 GB only zeroes.

Because, I can create a disk of **1GB** from a baseurl present already in windows azure portal,

but am not sure how to append zeroes/empty to the already created disk.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a 1 GB VHD with data and then increase its size to 2 GB. Take a look at this blog post: http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2013/01/07/Tales-from-the-trenches-resizing-a-Windows-Azure-virtual-disk-the-smooth-way.aspx. Source code is available on Github here: https://github.com/azure-contrib/WindowsAzureDiskResizer.